# GORM: unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type int64 into type *models.Team

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have issue with my first GORM usage. I want to load Point with preloaded Team structure. Go throw error that int64 cannot be stored in models.Team. I suppose that I have to use GORM the wrong way, but I am not able to find out why. Database contain data, relation many2many on other structs works fine for me (users in Team struct).

```
type Point struct {
    Id    int  `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    TeamX Team `gorm:"column:team_id;foreignKey:id"` // <<< this struct I want to get
    CreatedAt time.Time
    Note      string
}

func (Point) TableName() string {
    return "points"
}

type Team struct {
    Id    int `gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Name  string
    Users []User `gorm:"many2many:teams_users;"`
}

func (Team) TableName() string {
    return "teams"
}

var obj models.Point
    log.Println(getDatabase().Preload("Teams").First(&obj, 1).Error.Error())
    fmt.Println(obj.Id) // <<< this one loads ok
    fmt.Println(obj.TeamX.Id) // <<< this throw error
```

**points table**

id  int(11), auto_increment
team_id int(11), foreign key teams(id)
createdAt   datetime
note    text

**teams table**

id  int(11), auto_increment
name    text

> sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "team_id": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type int64 into type *models.Team

Comment: Solution for others
add TeamID with type int to Point struct

I have team_id in points table, not point_id in teams table